# Any major difference between Eclipse and Eclipse-EE?

Tags: eclipse

Any major difference between those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of code editing and compilation - no. The Eclipse EE has features to support "enterprise stuff".

Comment: If you do About Eclipse -> Installation Details, you can see the features that get installed with each one